# PHP post request by passing the values dynamically

Tags: php, node.js, express, body-parser

I am trying to pass two values name and company to the server but it always pass them as a string.

```
app.post('/visitors/store', (req, res) => {
const name = req.body.name; (User1)
const company = req.body.company; (Google)
con.query("INSERT INTO visitors(name, company) VALUES(`name`,`company`)", (results) => {
            res.json(results);
        });
  })
```

The problem is on this part of line "VALUES(`name`,`company`)"

The result in database atm: name = name , company = company

The results i need are : name = User1 , company = Google

Thanks for any help

Comment: I'm not an expert in node.js, but I guess that you should write something like this: `"INSERT INTO visitors(name, company) VALUES('" + name + "', '" + company + "')"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just brake the query string and include the actual variables inside:

```
app.post('/visitors/store', (req, res) => {
    const name = req.body.name;
    const company = req.body.company;
    con.query("INSERT INTO visitors(name, company) VALUES('" + name + "','" + company + "')", (results) => {
        res.json(results);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your environment you should also escape your query values.
If you use mysql you should be fine with something like this:

```
app.post('/visitors/store', (req, res) => {
const name = req.body.name;
const company = req.body.company;
con.query("INSERT INTO visitors(name, company) VALUES(?,?)", [name, company], (results) => {
    res.json(results);
});
```

or without escaping:

```
app.post('/visitors/store', (req, res) => {
const name = req.body.name;
const company = req.body.company;
con.query(`INSERT INTO visitors(name, company) VALUES(${name}, ${company})`, (results) => {
    res.json(results);
});
```